# tomcat8 unpack war always remove my smlink file

Tags: tomcat, war

When using command ./startup.sh in tomcat removed my symbolic link file.

How can I resolve this problem.

I don't want to remove my symbolic link file by tomcat.

Previous Description: My Environment [os: centos7, java: 1.8.0_131, spring version: 3.2.12.RELEASE]

1. install and unpack apache-tomcat-8.5.15
2. edit `<Host name="localhost" appBase="" unpackWars="true" autoDeply="true">` in `apache-tomcat-8.5.15/conf/server.xml`
3. execute command `mkdir /home/data`
4. execute command `ln -s /home/data apache-tomcat-8.5.15/uploadfiles`, `ln -s /home/data apache-tomcat-8.5.15/ROOT/uploadfiles`
5. File upload in `/home/data apache-tomcat-8.5.15/ROOT/uploadfiles` or `/home/data apache-tomcat-8.5.15/uploadfiles`
6. execute command `./startup.sh`
7. tomcat happen removed files in `apache-tomcat-8.5.15/ROOT/uploadfiles`

I want use img file in symbolic link, from img tag path. but when excuted command ./startup.sh my removed img file. downloadservlet is not good at me.

Comment: Please give steps to reproduce. My tomcat doesn't remove symbolic links.

Comment: You should edit your question rather than adding an answer or a comment for more information

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is doing exactly what you tell it to do: `<Host ... unpackWars="true">` means that war-files will be unpacked, and Tomcat's webapps directory should not be messed around with.

Further more: It's really bad practice to have an upload-directory right in tomcat's webapps directory, as you're opening yourself up to remote code execution vulnerabilities. Assume someone uploads a JSP file, then requests it: It will be compiled server-side and executed with the same permissions that Tomcat has. Not a pretty result.

You're probably linking this directory to separate the application from uploaded files, for backup purposes. There's no need to map any directory into the webapps directory. Just provide a DownloadServlet that serves files from preconfigured locations and you're set.